# UISearchBar in UITableView with .plist

Tags: uitableview, plist, uisearchbar

In past, I followed a little tutorial to achieve a UISearchBar in my UITableView.

It was made of arrays. Now that I have .plist file which handles everything, how would the searchBar be? 
I mean, I did something like:

```
 copyLists = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:sortedList copyItems:YES];
```

Where sortedList is the array which contains the plist.

Basically the searchBar works fine, but when I type in a word, it doesn't show any cells, even if I write the exact name of a cell.

Should it return the key `name` contained in the plist which is the name of the cell?

How would the searchBar change with plists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller shouldReloadTableForSearchString:(NSString *)searchString
{
    [self.filteredList removeAllObjects]; // First clear the filtered array.

    NSArray *objcts = unfilteredList;

    for (NSDictionary *section in objcts)
    {
        for (NSDictionary *row in [section valueForKey:@"Rows"])
        {
            NSRange rng = [[row valueForKey:@"name"] rangeOfString:searchString options:(NSCaseInsensitiveSearch|NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch)];

            if (rng.length != 0)
                [self.filteredList addObject:row];
        }
    }
    // Return YES to cause the search result table view to be reloaded.
    return YES;
}
```

make sure your `Search Bar and Search Display Controller` `delegate` are set right. Then for displaying the cell use:

```
NSArray *rows;
if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView)
{
    rows = filteredList;
} else {
    NSDictionary *section = [unfilteredList objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    rows = [section objectForKey:@"Rows"];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [[rows objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"name"];
```

and change the logic for `rowCount`, `titleHeader`, etc.

Comment: May I ask what the `@"Rows"` has to do with this? I'm kinda lost with my search function :|

Comment: the array is an array of sections, and each section has its own rows. I'm accessing this sub-dictionary with `objectForKey:@"Rows"`

Comment: How come I can't access my sub-directories. My main directory is Places, and my sub directory is Church. If I use your code, it gets me an exemption. :|

Comment: I think your dictionary is named like the place. So you have to use the place name as key `objectForKey:@"PlaceName"`. In this example there is a dic with many keys and values. One of them is called "Rows" and it contains an array with the rows.